# How to pass SlackEvents data to client side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack

I'm trying to create a simple chat based of the Slack API's. It's going well but I've hit a wall. I have this method:

```
slackEvents.on('message', (event) => {
    console.log(`Received a message event: user ${event.user} in channel ${event.channel} says ${event.text}`);
});
```

which triggers any time someone sends a message within the slack app.
However, I cannot figure out for the life of me how to send this information to the client when it's triggered!

I have tried res.send but obviously there is no res parameter given, it's not an `app.post` function so there is no response or anything. I've looked far and wide at their API but they really don't give many code examples.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const { WebClient, ErrorCode,  } = require('@slack/client');
const { createEventAdapter } = require('@slack/events-api');
const slackEvents = createEventAdapter(process.env.SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET);
app.use('/slackevents', slackEvents.expressMiddleware());
app.use(bodyParser.json())
slackEvents.on('message', (event) => {
    console.log(event);
    console.log(`Received a message event: user ${event.user} in channel ${event.channel} says ${event.text}`);
    res.send(event.text);
});
```

I want the line which prints on my server console, to be passed to the client side. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The usual solution to this problem is: all code of a Slack app is running on the server (e.g. node.js) not in the browser.

Comment: Do you mean the opposite of what you wrote? You mean running the code above in a script tag client side?

Comment: Do I understand your question correctly, that the below part of your code is supposed to run on the client(browser)? It would be unusual.

Comment: If you really want to run that code on the client you would need to store the event message on the server (e.g. in a queue) and then build your own API to retrieve those events from the client.